# insert a beep sound into an audio file for a particular word using python

Tags: python, audio, beep

Can anyone tell me how to insert a beep sound into an audio file for a particular word using python?

I am a beginner in python so I don't know much about it.Only thing which I get on Google is how to generate beep sound and not how I can add that beep sound into an audio.

Comment: It's more complex than you think...First you need to extract `sentences` from `audio file` with `Timestamps`..Later uisng `Regex` need to find at which `Timestamp` that word present. Simply break the audio at `word` based on `Time stamp`. merge `Beep.mp3` in miidle of the slot.You've to do `step-by-step`

Comment: Thankyou so much Bhargav. I'm gonna try it and hope that it will work .

Answer (score 1):

There's an `\a` escape sequence in computers that is only designed to produce `beep` sound.